# Story about a planet with curtain-like time 'zones'

Tags: story-identification

I've been looking for a long time for a link to a story I read, I think, in paperback over 20 years ago. Here's what I remember:

A planet with multiple 'zones' of time: past, present, and future all together and thinly separated by something I think was described as like 'curtains'.

These curtains move, as if blown by wind and some people, who weren't too far separated by time could actually interact. Some were close enough to get married, others, could only experience ghost-like contact because they were much further apart in time.

This might have been a book or in a sci-fi compilation. I simply don’t remember.

Comment: THAT'S IT!!!  Thank you! Already ordered on Amazon~!!!!

Comment: You're welcome! I've posted my answer as an Answer. If you wish, you can **accept** the answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer.

Answer (score 13):

[*The Veils of Azlaroc*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?7299) by [Fred Saberhagen](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?602). Here are the [covers](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?7299). Here is an [Amazon.com](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0812553241) review by Tab L. Uno:

> This short novel brings a life a most unique world and imaginatively brings together a number of characters from a multitude of different generations as a result of a mysterious physical phenomenon that annually can capture visitors to the planet and makes them prisoners in time. While not terribly dense or detailed, it reads easily and wraps the reader up in a special universe with intriguing interactions between characters, especially between generations. It is a magical, light book that will have you chuckling and sighing with sadness. It is about power, greed, lost romantic relationships, about the joy of acceptance, and the collision between people of different time periods. A fascinating story that has few parallels.

The novel *The Veils of Azlaroc* is an expansion of two shorter works, the short story ["To Mark the Year on Azlaroc"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?81728) and the novelette ["Beneath the Hills of Azlaroc"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?437811); the latter was published in [*Odyssey*, Spring 1976](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?161701+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Odyssey_v01n01_1976-Spring_Gorgon776#page/n46/mode/1up).